# How to pass translations with keys and values from Twig to a JavaScript object?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to pass translation strings as key-value pairs through a Twig template without having to assign them again one by one.

I have my translations in a file `translations/messages.fr.yaml`. Example:

```
entity:
  foo: some translation
  bar: another translation
  third:
    title: one more
```

Currently I pass translations through the Twig template in a JS code block, using the 'trans' filter:

```
const translations = {
  foo: "{{'entity.foo'|trans}}",
  bar: "{{'entity.bar'|trans}}",
  third: {
    title: "{{'entity.third.title'|trans}}"
  }
}
```

Is there a way how to pass all properties of 'entity' directly? Could I access the translations as an object and pass it into the variable via JSON (as a Twig variable or, if necessary, echoing something with `<?php ... ?>`)?

I'm aware that I could use AJAX but I am trying to pass the data in the template.

Comment: Is `entity` an array or an object? If it's an array you could traverse the keys, if it's an object you would need to cast/transform it to an array first

Comment: `entity` is a key in the YAML file where the translations are saved. https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with a function `getTranslations` that retrieves the catalogue and merges it with the fallback catalogue. Then it calls the recursive function `addToArray` to create a multi-dimensional array from the dot-separated key segments:

```
function addToArray(array $keySegments, array|string $translations, string $translation) : array|string 
{
    if (count($keySegments) === 0) {
        return $translation;
    }

    if (!is_array($translations)) {
        // syntax error in yaml file - a dot inside a key name
        return $translations;
    }

    $keySegment = array_shift($keySegments);
    if (!isset($translations[$keySegment])) {
        $translations[$keySegment] = [];
    }

    $translations[$keySegment] = addToArray($keySegments, $translations[$keySegment], $translation);

    return $translations;
}


function getTranslations(Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface $translator) : array
{
    // replace 'messages' with the required domain
    $catalogue = array_merge(
        $translator->getCatalogue()->getFallbackCatalogue()->all('messages'),
        $translator->getCatalogue()->all('messages')
    );
    $translations = [];
    foreach ($catalogue as $key => $translation) {
        $keySegments = explode('.', $key);
        $translations = array_merge($translations, addToArray($keySegments, $translations, $translation));
    }

    return $translations;
}
```

In the twig template I use the output in a script block:

```
const translations = JSON.parse(`{{translations|json_encode|raw}}`);
```